# Camera API not stopping after capture

Tags: java, android, api, camera

I have an app that uses the old camera API. Everything works fine on most devices, however, on some it will continue to preview even after the image is captured. The picture callback is still called but the preview does not stop. I really don't want to have to convert the image data to a bitmap and display it as it does have a second or so lag and looks bad. I was wondering if there were any work-arounds for the devices that it is not working for?

My capture buttons calls the following method

```
private void photoCapture()
{
    if (mCamera == null)
        return;
    toggleBar();
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    takenPicture = true;
}
```

Here is my callback

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        imageData = data;
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            frontFacing = true;
        }
    }
};
```

I was under the impressed that the takePicture method would automatically stop the preview? No?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that you are using. A million things could be wrong here.

Comment: Just edited. Please let me know if you need anything else. On the devices where it does not freeze, it still calls the callback method. Just doesn't stop the preview automatically like some devices do. @bremen_matt

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying a surface to preview the camera, then you should call camera.stopPreview() when you want the preview to stop. Otherwise, the preview will continue until the view is destroyed.